# WixUI_InstallDir and ARPNOREPAIR / ARPNOMODIFY properties

Tags: wix

I would like to delete repair / modify buttons from **Add or Remove Programs**.

I would also like to use **WixUI_InstallDir** Dialog Set.

This is my code:

```
<UI>
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir"/>
</UI>
<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLDIR"/>

<Property Id="ARPNOREPAIR" Value="yes" Secure="yes" />
<Property Id="ARPNOMODIFY" Value="yes" Secure="yes" />
```

But this causes

```
error LGHT0091 : Duplicate symbol 'Property:ARPNOMODIFY' found
```

I understand that **WixUI_InstallDir** defines these properties and the only decision I see is to define my own UI that is similar to **WixUI_InstallDir** except for these properties.
But is this the only way?
Can I overwrite these properties somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use setproperty.

```
<SetProperty Id="ARPNOMODIFY" Value="1" After="InstallValidate" Sequence="execute"/>
```