# WIX: Override ARPNOMODIFY with WixUI_InstallDir Dialog Set

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.8

I am using WIX Tool set to create MSI installer and i need to display **Change** button of Add and Remove Programs Menu. so, i set the property '**ARPNOMODIFY**' with  but i get a compiler error that **WixUI_InstallDir** already has defined this property. after investigating a lot , i found this link [WixUI_InstallDir and ARPNOREPAIR / ARPNOMODIFY properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997878/wixui-installdir-and-arpnorepair-arpnomodify-properties) but it doesn't work. The Change button still didn't displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just copy the source of the WixUI_InstallDir from [here](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/WixUI_InstallDir.wxs) and add a new wxs file in your project. You'll need to rename the UI Id from WixUI_InstallDir to something else. In your product just include a UIRef to the new UI defined in your new wxs file.

In this file you can change your ARPNOMODIFY property. I believe trying to set the property isn't working for you because SetProperty is a run-time change and the property in the MSI table is still the default defined value from when you built the installer.

I would suggest you investigate whether you really need to  enable the Change button on add remove programs. If you are using the base install UI with no modifications, the only thing you can really change is the install dir and it is a weird use case to install the product then decide you want to change its installation location, imo.

Comment: Hi Brian, I need this because i want to display Check box on uninstall to allow user to delete or leave some app related files and after a lot of investigations, this can be done only using Maintenance mode that allow full UI install sequence to display. If you have other option, or if i am wrong, you can advise me on how to do that